# How to get random item from array only from the specified keys (e.g x key first)

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have a `array` that i want to select two item as random, And two keys are selected between the key 2 and the key 8.

```
$arr = array=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

I can get two random item:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($arr, 2);

$arr[$rand_keys[0]]; // one
$arr[$rand_keys[0]]; // two
```

In the above code, It is possible that  selected items be from the entire array. Now i want to know how can I limit my choice?
In fact i want to get random item from this `array`:

```
array=(2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to first take a part of the array before you take random items from it

```
$part = array_slice($arr, 1, 7); // outputs array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Comment: I wanted the same thing, Thanks.

Comment: @stack did this solve your question, or do you still have an problem with the solution?

Comment: @stack then please mark my (or others') answer as the Solution to your problem, so when others have this question as well they can find the solution